# QBD Query Documentation

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have read the documentation on creating QBD Queries here: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit/query_filters/quickbooks_desktop

And the full SDK documentation here: http://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV2Doc/IntuitDataServicesSDK/

I'm trying to build a query in C# and .Net SDK 2.0  that takes a customer number from a text field and returns all invoices by that customer. Here's what I have so far:

```
var qbdInvoiceQuery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.InvoiceQuery();   
qbdInvoiceQuery.Item = "1";
qbdInvoiceQuery.ChunkSize = "10";
var qbdInvoices = qbdInvoiceQuery.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Invoice>(context).ToList();
grdQuickBooksInvoices.DataSource = qbdInvoices;
```

This works well, but I get all invoices. The query example at the above link is good, but I can't find documentation for filters beyond the CDCAsOf field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a filter on the Invoice query to get the invoices that belong to a certain customer. You can do something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<InvoiceQuery xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"><IncludeTagElements>Invoice/Header/CustomerName</IncludeTagElements>
</InvoiceQuery>
```

thanks,
Jarred

Comment: Thank you. I suppose I could write the query in XML, in which case, the documentation seems to be fine, but I would like to do it in C#. Could you show a code snippet in C# for how to add the filter?